# Why does my string content disappear in class method?

Tags: c++, class, wxwidgets

I have a class:

```
class aeMessage : public aeDialog
{
    const wxString* message;

public:
    aeMessage(const wxString& title, const wxString& message, const char* buttons[], const int button_count, const wxSize& size);
    void configurePanel(wxPanel* panel); // Overrides method in aeDialog
};

aeMessage::aeMessage(const wxString& title, const wxString& message, const char* buttons[], const int button_count, const wxSize& size)
    : aeDialog(title, buttons, button_count, size)
{
    this->message = &message;
    std::cout << "1 Message Address = " << this->message << "\n";
    std::cout << "2 Message Text = " << *this->message << "\n";
}
```

On construction the output is:

> 1 Message Address = 0x7ff7b9a9b920
> 2 Message Text = This is the About dialog

I have method in the class as follows:

```
void aeMessage::configurePanel(wxPanel *customPanel)
{
    // Create message box

    std::cout << "3 Message Address = " << this->message << "\n";
    std::cout << "4 Message Text = " << *this->message << "\n";
}
```

The output is:

> 3 Message Address = 0x7ff7b9a9b920
> 4 Message Text =

Can anyone help me understand why the content of the string has disappeared?
There is nothing that changes the the content of `this->message`.
thanks

The class is being created using:

```
void MyApp::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    // Show the About dialog box

    const int numberOfButtons{1};
    const char *buttons[numberOfButtons] = {"Ok"};
    aeMessage *custom = new aeMessage(wxT("Aetharcana"), "This is the About dialog", buttons, numberOfButtons, wxSize(600, 300));
    custom->show();
    std::cout << "Returned " << custom->getSelected() << "\n";
    custom->Destroy();
}
```

Comment: Your assumption about `this` is correct, but there is no way to diagnose your problem without seeing a [mcve] demonstrating how you are constructing and using the `aeMessage` object, and especially showing the lifetime of the `wxString` object that it is pointing at

Comment: Why are you using `wxString*` instead of just using `wxString`

Comment: I am just learning C++ and understood it to be better to pass pointer to a string than a string object. Perhaps I have misunderstood.

Comment: Presumably the `wxString` you're storing a pointer to has been destroyed, store it by value instead

Comment: You invite a dangling pointer, and it shows up.

Comment: "*[I] understood it to be better to pass pointer to a string than a string object*" - then you need to re-review whatever text told you that.

Comment: @n.m. There is more going on than just a dangling pointer. A dangling pointer doesn't change value, it just points to dead memory. This pointer in this case is changing value, so either the pointer itself is being corrupted, or the `this` pointer being used to reach it is invalid.

Comment: Ok, my mistake the address has not actually changed, I cut and paste from the output of two different runs. sorry.

Comment: If you want to avoid unnecessary copies usually a reference is better choice – this applies mainly for *function parameters*, though. In general if you want to use pointers or references outside of functions – or in multi-threaded environment – you need a pretty clear image about the life-time of the object referred/pointed at! Use of smart pointers can help avoid trouble around – though back at the specific case I have some doubts about `wxString` being worth all this trouble...

Comment: Clearly I need to go away and under stand better how strings work.

Comment: Sidenote: `// Overrides method in aeDialog` – there's `override` *keyword* now – use that one instead of commenting the intention. Further advantage: If the function doesn't actually override (implementation error or change of base class interface) the compiler diagnoses it automatically.

Comment: *'Clearly I need to go away and under stand better how strings work.'* – not really the strings, but life time of objects in general ;)

Comment: The point is: If you use pointers or references, no matter if to string or to anything else, you need to make sure that as long as the pointer still is in use the object pointed to is alive, too. The infamous *counter* example: Returning a reference or pointer to a local variable like `int& f() { int n; return n; }` – this little example function returns a reference to a variable that doesn't exist any more on leaving the function – a *dangling* reference, as mentioned already.

Comment: `Clearly I need to go away and under stand better how strings work` No. That's not strings. THat's literally every object in C++ memory model. You should read and pay attention closely to memory model description and object life time. And in C++ object means any storage type, even an `int` or `float`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 issues happening:

- You are passing a string literal to the`message` parameter of your constructor, so the compiler has to create a temporary `wxString` object, which your constructor is then storing a pointer to. That temporary is destroyed as soon as your constructor exits, thus leaving the `this->message` pointer dangling.
- the value of `this->message` is not consistent, which implies that your `aeMessage::configurePanel()` method is not being called on the same `aeMessage` object that you constructed. However, the sample code you have shown does not demonstrate this usage.

Comment: Thank you, I think the value of the pointer is consistent, my mistake was copying the output from two different runs. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Cromwell1963 please fix your question to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your comments and suggestions. I have now passed and stored the string by value instead of as a pointer and everything works as expected. Thanks!